# php: file_get_contents() work with CLI, but does not work when called on server (in page)

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am slightly baffled.

I am using the bit.ly PHP API to shorten some urls. This works fine on local host - but when I tried it on my server (php running in Apache), file_get_contents() returns an empty string.

I checked my apache logs and cannot see any warning/errors by Apache, so I tried the same command at the CL  (using PHP CLI):

```
>php -a
php > $long_url = some_url_encoded_string;
php > echo file_get_contents($long_url);
{"errorCode": 0, "errorMessage": "", "results": {"http://www.example.html": {"userHash": "abc", "shortKeywordUrl": "", "hash": "xyz", "shortCNAMEUrl": "http://bit.ly/foobar", "shortUrl": "http://bit.ly/foobar"}}, "statusCode": "OK"}
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: Does the server run SELinux?  If so, there's an SELinux boolean `httpd_can_network_connect` which must be turned on.  I assume `allow_url_fopen` is turned on in php.ini if it works from the CLI

Comment: @Michael: No, the server is a headless Ubuntu 10.0.4 LTS install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably has something to do with PHP configuration. Many servers have different php.inis for CLI and Apache. Check /etc/php5/ to see if there is more than one configuration. Specifically, you should be looking for [allow_url_fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen).

EDIT: Actually, Ubuntu ships with that by default, the .ini is located at /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Comment: Yes. allow_url_fopen was Off. Being the impatient 'so and so' that I am, I got this fixed (since I didn't know how long before I got an answer), by using curl instead. I'll accept your answer anyways. Thanks for the prompt response!