# PHP: file_get_contents behaves differently

Tags: php, apache, root, file-get-contents

I use file_get_contents to activate something on the server side. The simple call of

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://10.155.0.2/dir/somepage.html');
```

should do it. It works fine if I call the script that contains this line in the browser, but it doesn't if I call it on the command line. And I don't know why. In both cases I get the same content. At least I'm quite sure about this, but I have only very rare chances to check this. I know this could be bad to get helpful answers.

**But I can reduce the problem to the following:**

In one case the script is executed by the apache user in the other case I executed as root on the command line. The activation works with the apache user, with the root user it doesn't. Simple question now:

Can the different execution of the script `(cli/root vs. browser/apache)` containing file_get_contents influence this call anyhow?

**Does it influence the headers of file_get_contents? Is there a way to check this?**

Comment: You said: "In both cases I get the same content". What's the difference in execution? I couldn't understand it from your explanation.

Comment: Calling the script from browser, what causes an apache execution, and calling it on the server from command line as root.

Comment: Maybe your browser environment knows about 10.155.0.2, but console env does not?

Comment: what "does not work"? Do you get an error message?

Comment: I think the browser does not (need to) know about 10.155.0.2.

Comment: if it helps you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874857/php-file-get-contents-work-with-cli-but-does-not-work-when-called-on-server

Comment: @Gerald: The activation does not work. I don't know about what is going on 10.155.0.2, I just see that there is difference how my script is called. There is no error message - unfortunately.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: No error message means: file_get_contents returns some expected html code in both cases. That means from the view of my script the call works properly. However, I know something was done differently on the remote server. I supspect the remote could evaluate some header values which are different with the different executions. But in both cases some html code is returned from this remote server.

Comment: No need to scoff. I didn't want you to anylize my actual problem. I reduced it to the question, if file_get_contents could behave differently with different executions. If someone tells me that this cannot be the case then my problem is somewhere else and I have to find it out by myself. You obviously cannot help me with this. But maybe one can tell me if file_get_contents could work differently (I suspect the headers could be different). This would help me already. And @www.sblog.in: no, all php settings are all the same. I checked this with ini_get_all().

Comment: Sorry, it was not my intention to scoff, I've removed the offending comments. It's simply that we cannot read your mind: whatever you omit, will never reach us. Good luck.